# How to find out which rake task in Heroku scheduler is resulting in a R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I see R14 errors in my Heroku logs

```
Apr 17 10:50:46 clinch heroku/run.2831:  Process running mem=558M(109.1%) 
Apr 17 10:50:47 clinch heroku/run.2831:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

From the `heroku/run.2831` part, I can tell it is one of the rake tasks scheduled using the Heroku Scheduler that is running out of memory.

However, I have several rake tasks scheduled using the Heroku scheduler. How do I tell which one is using up more than 512MB of memory?

Answer (score -1):

The heroku scheduler dashboard should show you when each task was last run. You could check to see which one was running at that time.